# Gitlab version update

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, version

I am trying to upgrade my GitLab docker container from version 13.8.0 to 13.8.8 with ce edition.
I tried by download the Debian package for the ubuntu focal version from the below link:

`https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/focal/gitlab-ce_13.8.8-ce.0_amd64.deb`

but while installing the package I am getting the following errors...

```
root@2d66229ecf41:/tmp#dpkg -i gitlab-ce_13.8.8-ce.0_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 86705 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gitlab-ce_13.8.8-ce.0_amd64.deb ...
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.7)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.7)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.7)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.7)
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.7)
dpkg: error processing archive gitlab-ce_13.8.8-ce.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce_13.8.8-ce.0_amd64.deb
```

what I should I do?
My disc space is also free...
what is the problem?

can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, ruby needs xcrypt v2.0, glibc_2.xx and they are not installed or unable to be found.

This is the first step I would try, after performing a [backup](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html#backup):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2438576